# Exclude users with zero score from ranking

Tags: mysql

I've come across this great solution to rank users based on their score in mysql.

```
SELECT  d.*, c.ranks
FROM
        (
          SELECT    Score, @rank:=@rank+1 Ranks
          FROM
                  (
                      SELECT  DISTINCT Score 
                      FROM    tableName a
                      ORDER   BY score DESC
                  ) t, (SELECT @rank:= 0) r
        ) c 
        INNER JOIN tableName d
            ON c.score = d.score
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to exclude users with 0 or without score from the ranking, but still return these users in the results.

So for example

```
KEY     username    password    score   Ranks
1       Anna        123         8       1
2       Bobby       345         5       2
3       Helen       678         5       2
4       Jon         567         -2      3
5       Arthur      ddd         -9      4
4       Chris       444         0       
5       Liz         eee         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to SELECT all of your users, start with that:

```
SELECT
  user.*
FROM user
```

Now, we want to add in a table of ranked users, so we'll start to add in complexity. We're aiming to get a temporary table of ranked users, so we'll LEFT JOIN as to not filter out any non-ranked users.

```
SELECT
  user.*,
ranked_user.score,
ranked_user.rank
FROM user
LEFT JOIN(
  // subquery
) AS ranked_user ON ranked_user.user_id = user.id
```

Then we'll have to figure out the section for the subquery where the ranks are determined. You have most of it already, I'm just going to add in an `IF` statement to only assign a rank if they have a score. Altogether, you get this:

```
SELECT
  user.*,
  ranked_user.score,
  ranked_user.rank
FROM user
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT
    score,
    user_id,
    IF(score = 0 OR score IS NULL, null, @rank:=@rank+1) AS rank
  FROM(
    SELECT
      DISTINCT score,
      user_id
    FROM stat
    ORDER BY score DESC
  ) t, (SELECT @rank:= 0) r
) ranked_user ON ranked_user.user_id = user.user_id
```

Here's how that `IF` statement works:

```
IF(score = 0 OR score IS NULL,
# if c.score is 0 or missing

null,
# set the value to null

@rank:=@rank+1) 
# otherwise, calculate a rank

AS rank
# call this value "rank"
```

Just a side note: I'd change `user.*` and actually list each column of `user` that you want. That's considered best practice.

Comment: A little confused as to where that goes?

Comment: @user1019144 top of your code. You just need to change `c.ranks` to the `IF` statement. Look at the code and my explanation and think about what it's doing - should make it more clear where it goes and why.

Comment: It works, but it is including the 0's in the ranking just not returning the rank. So for example all of the 0's are ranking the same, and the negative scores, are skipping the rank which all the 0' share... Does that make sense.

Comment: So in the sample data -2 score is showing as ranking 5, and -9 score is showing ranking 6 , and the zeros are not showing ranking

Comment: with the new answer i'm no longer getting the rows with score 0 in the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72387/discussion-between-m59-and-user1019144).